# Ploting multiple curves on the same axes using plot handles

Tags: matlab, plot

Is there a method to plot multiple curves on the same axes, but using plot handles. To be specific, I am looking for something similar to

```
plot_handle = plot(x, y1, x, y2);

for i= 1:n
  set(plot_handle, 'XData', x, 'YData', y1, 'XData', x, 'YData', y2)
  drawnow
end
```

But this does not work. Only y2 is plotted. Is there a command that has a similar effect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `plot_handle` from your first line will be a two-element vector. Within the loop, set the values of each of the plots separately:

```
set(plot_handle(1), 'XData', x, 'YData', y1)
set(plot_handle(2), 'XData', x, 'YData', y2)
```

Answer (score 0):

add a

```
hold on
```

after the plot command in the for loop.

```
for i= 1:n
  set(plot_handle, 'XData', x, 'YData', y1, 'XData', x, 'YData', y2);hold on
  drawnow
end
```